# What English construction matches the Boolean condition of nand?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, logic

English language usage has some logical word pairs including:

- Or | Nor
- Either | Neither
- With | Without

But there doesn't seem to be an opposition to the word "and". In computer engineering and Boolean logic, this is referred to as a "nand" operation.

For example, if I were to say "I eat pancakes when they have bananas nand strawberries in them," then what I want to communicate is that:

- I *will* eat a pancake with bananas
- I *will* eat a pancake with strawberries
- I *will* eat a pancake with *neither* bananas nor strawberries
- I *won't* eat a pancake with specifically *both* bananas and strawberries

Is there an equivalent of the boolean operand **nand** in the English language (or a short phrase and not just a rearranging of the sentence)? Essentially, not how to say the phrase with the same meaning, but if there's a short phrase or word that conveys the same meaning. This question intends "to be less about the missing 'nand' word and more about how to express the condition it represents" (Chris Subagio).

Comment: For whatever the reasons I don't think it's the best word for it as it could cause confusion when spoken and the first word ends in n: `You are permitted a pen nand paper`. Nor tends to be preceeded with neither so you usually know it's coming but nand presumably wouldn't be.

Comment: Because we say "don't have" rather than "have (this nand that)"

Comment: I’d be more likely to say that I don’t like strawberries and bananas together in my pancakes.

Comment: The word would be useless since English doesn't have Boolean logic.

Comment: That only works if he would accept pancakes without either fruit, Jim. I think the  issue rarely comes up comes up because, "either", "or" or a combination of both usually does the job. When it does, we just append something to further ascertain it.

Comment: There's **sans.**  For instance, "I like banana splits sans strawberries."  Doesn't technically answer your question about "and" having an opposite, but it's a short word that means something like *nand* woulda.

Comment: @HotLicks That seems like it should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @MishaRosnach - *sans* is simply a hoity-toity way to say *without*.

Comment: Consider that it's difficult to process *nand* "in your head" even when you know you're dealing with Boolean logic -- you usually need to write the values down to be sure you're processing them properly.  (At least I do, and I've been in the computer biz for 45 years.)  English is a *spoken* language, and words that are only meaningful on paper will never gain "traction", even if they were to attain some degree of theoretical legitimacy.

Comment: @Tonepoet- Exactly, that's what he says.  "I eat pancakes when they have bananas nand strawberries in them" -> ~(0 & 0) = T

Comment: Woof! To clarify, a NAND in boolean logic is true if either or both of the operands are false. So the pancake would only be *un*acceptable if it had both strawberries *and* bananas. Any other combination, only strawberries, only bananas or neither at all, would all be fine.

Comment: Huh, my impression was that he was looking for an xor (exclusive or) type word.

Comment: Well, he very specifically brought up 'nand', which is a portmanteau of "not and", and proceeded to describe it as being in opposition to the state described by 'and'. To deduce the meaning for 'nand', you just need to negate the conditions for 'and' which are: "both operands must be true". So of the four possible states of operands, "true/true", "false/true", "true/false" and "false/false", nand gives you a true for anything that isn't "true/true".

Comment: @HotLicks: I think you mean to say that **sans** is a *synonym* for **without**.  And yes, I know - that's why I brought it up.

Comment: @ChrisSubagio Exactly! Thanks for clarifying for others.

Comment: The word you are looking for is simply ***or***.

Comment: @tchrist The word **or** has a different meaning than if **nand** was used. The intent is to mean that it is acceptable when neither are present, or only one is, but not both at the same time (which **or** doesn't convey).

Comment: Just as a NAND gate has two components (an AND gate with an inverter on its output), so English doesn't have a construction that makes this simple. To be understood, you'd end up expressing the combination of OR and NOR: "I'll eat a pancake with bananas or strawberries, even plain, but not both."

Comment: No problem. I'm actually curious to know if anyone has a good answer. I've been using "neither x and or y" for many years when reading a nand statement out loud. I suspect the answer is that there is no construct to represent the idea succinctly in mainstream English, and that @PaulRowe is quite right.

Comment: Sadly, I think you're right: that there is no English construct for this.

Comment: Still, I think it ought to be reopened since it was closed because the true meaning of the question was understood incorrectly, but edits have been made to clarify it, even though there seems to be no good word/phrase for **nand**.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 - I agree.   Even "is there a conjunction or word pairing for nand?"

Comment: "X or Y (or nothing) but not both". It's not a common situation so not surprising there's no simple phrasing for it.

Answer (score 4):

I would use unless/both:

"I eat pancakes *unless* they have *both* bananas and strawberries in them."

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best would be "I will eat a pancake, as long as it doesn't contain both bananas and strawberries."

This is a bit awkward, because there isn't really a specific English word for this concept. In fact **you can tell that there isn't really one** simply because they had to make up a word for it in the computer realm. Nearly all such computer terms were created by English speakers, so they use English terms. For example, the father of the particular ("boolean") algebraic system you are talking about was English Mathematician [George Boole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole).

Mathematicly "as long as it doesn't contain both ..." is equivalent to saying "**n**ot (A **and** B)", which is of course where the name for the **nand** operation came from.

Comment: This made me realize this got reopened :D And good point on the word origin; if there was one it'd probably be called that and not **nand**.

Answer (score 2):

"It's cloudy or it's sunny" [A OR B] has the inverse "It is not cloudy and not sunny." [not A AND not B].  This, as you say, can be rephrased, "It is neither cloudy nor sunny." [A NOR B]

"It's cloudy and it's raining" [AND] can be negated "It's not cloudy or it's not raining," [not A OR not B] which is the result using DeMorgan's.  But you're right, there's no way to say, "It's neither cloudy nand raining," and have it mean that either A or B is not true, or that both A and B are not true.  We DeMorgan's it into an OR statement of some sort.

If there's a combination of two or fewer terms for "neither" and "nand" that you can insert into "It's ____ cloudy ___ raining" that implies that one or both is not true, then you'd have your "nand."  But it doesn't exist, and if you tried to coin it, you'd likely end up explaining what you mean with a more natural and longwinded OR statement.

Comment: Conceivably that would be "It's not cloudy and or raining", which is what I use, and I think actually conveys the meaning in question despite parsing incorrectly as Boolean logic. I've also said "It's neither cloudy and or raining", which sounds better to my ear, but is more often confused. Full disclosure: when I'm feeling belligerent, I do say, "well, it's neither cloudy and nor raining" for the extra emphasis on that second 'n' in nor, but that really flabbergasts people.

Comment: @ChrisSubagio Not sure that covers the situation when it is cloudy but not raining to my ear.   The problem in English may be best expressed by what you and I are trying to do... use two "natural" conjunctions-- and/or-- to express what nand expresses in one.  The cases 00 01 10 are simply difficult to convey succinctly.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

*It is much simpler to say "I eat pancakes when they have bananas nand strawberries in them" than to say "I eat pancakes when they don't have both strawberries and bananas in them."*

Why not say:

*"I eat pancakes when they haven't strawberries and bananas in them."*

That is simpler than your second sentence and doesn't require extra vocabulary.

Comment: Because that wouldn't come across as the same thing. That sounds like he doesn't accept bananas or strawberries on his pancakes, which is untrue. He accepts only either alone, or neither at all. The only thing he objects to is both at the same time.

Comment: So put a *both* in the sentence. "I don't eat pancakes with both strawberries and bananas."